# What are MEAN and STD in Tensorflow Tflearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

When I launch TFLearn examples, I get this

Preprocessing... Calculating mean over all dataset (this may take long)...
Mean: 0.916834 
Preprocessing... Calculating std over all dataset (this may take long)...
STD: 0.227089

I don't understand what they are. I googled it , I looked on SO, I read http://tflearn.org/data_preprocessing/ I found that:

mean: Provides a custom mean

std: Provides a custom standard derivation

So what is "custom mean" for?
What is "custom derivation" for?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are running [this](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/data_preprocessing.py) file.

The mean it is computing is the global mean as can be seen in the following snippet:

```
print("Preprocessing... Calculating mean over all dataset "
      "(this may take long)...")
self._compute_global_mean(dataset, session, limit)
```

Go through the `_compute_global_mean` method, it is just calling `np.mean` on `dataset`

It is similar with `std`

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at _compute_global_mean. Right now I still do not understand what "mean" means... and then how to interpret the value.

Comment: mean is just the sum of all numbers in all the matrices divided by the number of such numbers, that's the usual mean, nothing surprising.

Answer (score 0):

**What is Mean and STD (Standard Deviation)**

They don't have a special meaning in Tensorflow but are statistical tools to understand a set of numbers.

> Mean: is just the average of a set of numbers.
>
> STD: is how far (on average) the numbers are from the mean.

Eg. consider set of just 2 numbers `3 and 6` (very simplified but the concept is the same for any amount of numbers).

`Mean` (or average) = `(3 + 6)/2 = 4.5` (sum of all numbers divided by the count).

`STD: = 1.5` ( 3 is 1.5 away from 4.5 and 6 is also 1.5 away from 4.5 so on average the numbers are 1.5 away from the mean ie STD)